# POWER_OF_FIVE_128 Cost and usage in rust core

Tags: rust, embedded

I am struggling  with minimizing my code size. While I was checking my code I found a ten kilobyte table here in [core](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/core/src/num/dec2flt/table.rs). First of all I am curious  what's the goal of this table and how can I avoid it?

```
pub static POWER_OF_FIVE_128: [(u64, u64); N_POWERS_OF_FIVE] = [
    (0xeef453d6923bd65a, 0x113faa2906a13b3f), // 5^-342
    (0x9558b4661b6565f8, 0x4ac7ca59a424c507), // 5^-341
    (0xbaaee17fa23ebf76, 0x5d79bcf00d2df649), // 5^-340
    ...
```

Comment: While I'm not completely sure how it gets used, the comments do mention that it can be removed by striping the binary. I am not familiar with the process for building embedded code. Are you able to use `strip` like with other executables? Are you able to employ other regular approaches for reducing binary size like the ones listed in this guide (https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust)?